# How to prevent disabled edittext from gaining focus?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-databinding, focusable

***Scenario:***
A sign up page with username and password edittexts.
Enable password only when username entered is valid.

**Layout XML:**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    ...>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/username_edit_text"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:onTextChanged="@{model::onUsernameTextChanged}"
        .../>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    ...>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_fragment_password_edit_text"
        android:enabled="@{safeUnbox(model.isUsernameValid)}"
        android:focusable="@{safeUnbox(model.isUsernameValid)}"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:onTextChanged="@{model::onPasswordTextChanged}"
        .../>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

**View model:**

```
var isUsernameValid: ObservableField<Boolean> = ObservableField(false)

// On username text changed
fun onUsernameTextChanged(usernameString: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {

    // Update username validity
    isUsernameValid.set(usernameString.length >= 8)
}
```

The observable field `isUsernameValid` is updated in `onUsernameTextChanged()` in the view model.

***Problem with the above code:***
Password editext is enabled when valid username is entered but the edittext is not focusable.

Removing `android:focusable="@{safeUnbox(model.isUsernameValid)}"` makes the edittext gain focus even if no valid username is entered by using soft keyboard next action.

Comment: @SumitShukla I am not doing anything in activity, everything is done in viewmodel. Updated my viewmodel code with text changed methods.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make use of:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText/>
```

instead of:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText/>
```

**For this problem** : Password editext is enabled when valid username is entered but the edittext is not focusable.

Use `editText.requestFocus()` to make edittext focused after enabling it. Also consider using `TextWatcher` for edittext to simplify validation purposes.